# swift how to dock inputAccessoryView above UIToolbar (not to the bottom)

Tags: ios, swift, inputaccessoryview

I have implemented the custom inputAccessoryView that is correctly shown above the keyboard when it is present.

The problem is that at the bottom of the screen I have UIToolbar.
And when keyboard is dismissed my custom inputAccessoryView is docked to the bottom of the screen and covers the UIToolBar.

Is there any way to dock inputAccessoryView above the UIToolbar when the keyboard is dismissed?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the code?

Answer (score 1):

Not easily no, because the `inputAccessoryView` will always be above your view as it's in a different window. It will come with a lot of complications.

Have you tried using `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` with an accessoryView in your self.view hierarchy?

First in your View Controller subscribe to the notifications

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Then also in your View Controller

```
func keyboardWillShow(notification:NSNotification) {

    self.transitionWithKeyboardInfo(notification.userInfo!)
}


func transitionWithKeyboardInfo(userInfo:NSDictionary) {

    let durationNumber = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey]
    let duration = durationNumber?.doubleValue

    let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey]
    let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.unsignedLongValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseInOut.rawValue
    let animationCurve = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

    let endFrameValue = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]
    let keyboardEndFrame = self.view.convertRect(endFrameValue!.CGRectValue, fromView:nil)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(duration!, delay: 0.0, options: animationCurve, animations: {

       // Now use keyboardEndFrame.size.height to move your view upwards

       // you can find out if you're dismissing or showing and do different animations here

        }, completion: nil)
}
```

Don't forget to remove the notification observation in dealloc / viewWillDisappear

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
```

Using `ScrollViewDidScroll` for your interactive accessory view movements...

```
var startingPoint:CGPoint


func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {   

    self.startingPoint = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(scrollView)
}

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {   

    let currentPoint = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.locationInView(scrollView)

    let deltaY = currentPoint.y - self.startingPoint.y
}
```

That should be everything you need to work out if you're touch is intercepting the accessoryView frame... then you can decide how to transition it with the keyboard... The easiest is what Google Hangouts do and transition the accessory view into the keyboard as separate entities... It's perhaps not 100% what you want, but after a while I made my peace with it and made it look good.

Comment: This thing is that I also need to swipe the keyboard (self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .Interactive) and in this case my inputAccessoryView should follow the keyboard while it is swiping down.
I thought to make the inputAccessoryView at first follow the keyboard and then when reaching the uitoolbar to make the inputAccessory view stay above the uitoolbar

Comment: This can still be done, but it's quite complicated. Use `scrollIndicatorInsets`  and `contentInset` of the `tableView` / `scrollView` / whatever as you drag downwards using `scrollViewDidScroll` to move the `accessoryView` you'll find that it only moves as you touch the keyboard, so you need to detect when you've touched the accessory view and start the process then if this is unacceptable. Use Google Hangouts as an example.

Comment: Magoo, you know, I'm stuck :( `scrollViewDidScroll` function works perfectly, but I can't detect when my accessory view is touched.
I tried to use `touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent...)` function but seems to me it doesn't work for `UIViewController` now. Also I have tried `UITapGestureRecognizer` but it gives me the coordinates when the touched ends and not the right ones. Is there any way to know the accessory view is touched? And then how do I move the accessory view by myself? (as I understand the accessory view is moved automatically according to keyboard movements)

Comment: As I see now in the function `scrollViewDidScroll`  `scrollView.contentOffset` are not the real points that the finger was moved. They are rather some scroll offset. Am I right? So my view moves not so fast as the keyboard does its movement..
I tried also the `UITapGestureRecognizer` and it works fine - shows the real points I press and move, but the problem now is that the INTERACTIVE keyboard dismiss mode doesn't work at all - I can move my view that is above the keyboard (I am using now the common view, not the accessory view) but the keyboard is not moved when I move my finger above it :(

Comment: It's an incredibly complicated task :D so don't give up! but there is a way I found. Use `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` and store a `CGPoint` `self.startingPoint = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];` by the same token, in `scrollViewDidScroll` using `CGPoint currentPoint = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];` will get you the current point... then you can do `currentPoint.x - self.startingPoint.x` and `currentPoint.y - self.startingPoint.y` to get the delta change :)